# Missing org.sonatype.nexus.cfg file, how to proceed?

Tags: nexus, nexus3

Nexus OSS 3.7.1-02 running on RHEL 7. I have several repositories on it and I am able to publish and retrieve packages and jars, therefore, I presume that the setup is working correctly.

In the [official documentation](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/security.html#ssl-inbound), I am referring to the 'Serving SSL Directly' section which uses the embedded Jetty server for serving https connections.

I am unable to find the file '$install-dir/etc/org.sonatype.nexus.cfg' mentioned in the documentation and there are a couple of config. around this file. I executed a find command for that file on the root directory but the file doesn't exist at all.

Another confusing step is:

> Edit $install-dir/etc/org.sonatype.nexus.cfg. Change the nexus-args
>   property comma delimited value to include
>   ${karaf.etc}/jetty-https.xml.

Now there's neither any directory under the 'karaf' directory nor does the file exist there but I found one jetty-https.xml file under nexus-3.7.1-02/etc/jetty.

How shall I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't the official documentation, it's the documentation for "3.0".  The official documentation is here: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3 (unversioned).
Specifically, I suspect you're looking for this: https://help.sonatype.com/display/NXRM3/Configuring+SSL.

Anyway, that file was replaced in an older version.
It now resides in ${data-dir}/etc/nexus.properties.